# Hibernate Search: 'Can't build query for type x.y.z.EntityA which is neither indexed nor has any indexed sub-types'

Tags: java, maven, hibernate-search

I have some mock code to test hibernate-search. When I ran the code, it gave me following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000278: Can't build query for type x.y.z.A.EntityA' which is neither indexed nor has any indexed sub-types.
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedQueryContextBuilder$HSearchEntityContext.<init>(ConnectedQueryContextBuilder.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedQueryContextBuilder.forEntity(ConnectedQueryContextBuilder.java:37)
    at x.y.z.A.maventTest.testHibernateSearch2(maventTest.java:36)
    at x.y.z.A.maventTest.main(maventTest.java:18)
```

Following is my Hibernate configuration file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">....</property>
        <property name="connection.username">....</property>
        <property name="connection.password">....</property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">...</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">.....</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.exclusive_index_use">true</property>

        <mapping class="x.y.z.EntityA" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

EntityA is the entity that has already been indexed using a different hibernate-search application. In this mock app it is indexed as:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class EntityA {...}
```

Following are the maven dependencies I am using:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hynnet</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle-driver-ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>           
            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>    

    </dependencies>
```

I am getting fullTextSession with:

```
public static FullTextSession getFullTextSession() {
        if (sessionFactory == null)
            configureSessionFactory();
        return Search.getFullTextSession(getSession());
    }

private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory()
            throws HibernateException {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate-search.cfg.xml");

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

From the stacktrace it clearly says that entity is not indexed. But, it is already indexed in filesystem and I have properly specified the index location.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Were is this run? The indexed type needs to be the same class as the one managed by Hibernate ORM; could it be that you have multiple class definitions which all have the name `x.y.z.A.EntityA` ?

Comment: The index I was referring to was managed by Hibernate-search-orm 4.5.1 while I was trying to access that index with Hibernate-search-orm 5.5.5. I switched back to 4.5.1 to access it and then worked. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Sanne I reindexed EntityA with Hibernate-search-orm 5.5.5 and tried to access it. It is again giving me same error as mentioned above i.e. 'Can't build query for type '....' which is neither indexed nor has any indexed sub-types.'

Comment: With Hibernate-search-orm 5.3.0.Final, I was able to get successful results with even using indices indexed by prior version. Any hibernate-search-orm after 5.3.0.Final is giving me error "Can't build query for type......." even if the indices are indexed by same version of hibernate-search-orm

Comment: would you be able to share an as small as possible example project which is able to reproduce this? Feel free to create a JIRA on https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH/issues and attach it, we'll investigate. I could bet you have a classloading problem though.

Comment: Also note that your strategy to start a new SessionFactory is not threadsafe: it's possible you might be starting multiple instances of Hibernate and that would have various critical side effects.